# Why do I recover ancient data with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 4 and jQuery 3.2.1.

I've got two buttons in a modal, which when I open defines an attribute to those buttons with `$('#button').attr()`. After that, I have an event when button is clicked which tries to get the data back from the button attribute with `$('#button').data()`.

Everything works fine when I call the modal for the first time. But when it's the second call or more... The value of the data I recover is the value of the first call.

Here is the full code :

```
$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

    var tag = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var deviceId = tag.data('device');

    $('#button1').attr("data-example", example);
    $('#button2').attr("data-example", example);

    // Other code here

});

$('#button1').on("click", function () {
    var example = $(this).data("example");

    console.log("Example : " + example);
});
```

Comment: why are you not using .data to set the data?

Comment: $('#button1').data("example", example);

Comment: Every time the modal is shown, you assign the example's variable value to data-example custom attribute in both buttons. How does example variable gets updated?

Comment: Ok it works fine with the .data("example", example). But how is it different from .attr() ? I see that the html isn't updated so how the first called to attr() worked when I recover the data with .data() ?

Comment: data() stores data, associated with the element, in memory. On the other hand, attr() changes the element's attributes

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)